# Visual Studio 2012 Faltan referencias

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un problema con referencias en mi proyecto de Visual Studio 2012. ¿Alguien tiene idea cómo solucionar esto? Ya me descargué algunos updates del framework y traté de actualizar algunos paquetes pero aun así tengo este error.
El problema pienso que está en las versiones con la que se creó el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si abres el el solucion explorer donde dice "references" puede ver que estan las librerias bien referenciadas, no hay ninguna con algun alerta en amarillo. Por el mensaje pareciera que nuget no descargo las librerias

Comment: SI creo que hay algun problema con nuget, ya intente de distintas formas y no he podido alguna idea amigo?@leandro-tuttini  ![Imagen](http://prnt.sc/d4c1d3).

Comment: Me parece que es por el tipo de proyecto con extencion *.csproj* pero aun no logro hacerlo funcionar

Comment: en algunas ocaciones me pasa algo similar, y se soluciona desde algo tan simple como reiniciar el VS, en otras debo borrar la carpeta package y que nuget vuelva a descargar o por ultimo borrar de `reference` los dll y ejecutar en la consola de nuget  `install packages.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si has validado que las referencias no estan correctas podrias validar nuget por medio de `Tools -> Options`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien podrias actualizar nuget por medio `Tools -> Extension Manager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede que actualizarlo haga que actualice as librerias

Tambien valida si tienes la carpeta package a nivel del .sln, y si hay contenido dentro de este, si eliminas lo que tenga dentro al compilar nuget deberia descargar las librerias nuevamente

Puede que tengas que marcar las opcines que permiten descargar automaticamente los packages

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]